# Issue :: Microsoft Cognitive Services :: client-sdk :: Azure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I am trying to use Azure cognitive services and trying to convert "Text To Speech". I am able to convert the Text to Speech successfully on my local machine. The issue only happens when I deploy my application to Azure cloud using "App Services".
I am getting the following error/exception when my code tries to create SpeechConfig e.g;
SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig(mySubscriptionKey,service-region)

**Exception:** UnsatisfiedLinkError

**I am using the following tech stack on Azure cloud:**
Spring Boot 2.6.7
Linux
(Tomcat embedded container) used by Spring Boot.
client-jar-sdk 1.14.0 (com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech)

I am **NOT** using any Container or Container Service like Kubernetes in this example. It is a simple webapp deployed to Azure using App Services.

**Note 1:** Please note that I have also tried to use Microsoft cognitive services client-sdk (1.21.0), but I am getting the same exception.
I went on google and found that other people were facing the same issue, but there was no satisfactory answer given.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/660957/text-speech-when-speechconfig-init-got-error.html

**Note 2:** Please note that I am **NOT** using a free subscription and the resource group region is **eastus**.

**Note 3:** I have tried and deployed many code examples (for the Text to Speech) provided my Microsoft and other people on the internet but I am getting the same issue in the Azure Platform **ONLY**.

**Exception Snapshot:**
[The following is the exception snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRWS0.png)

**Exception Details:**
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734458231Z 2022-05-14 18:17:32.733 ERROR 164 --- [p-nio-80-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] **threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.util.IntRef, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'] with root cause
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734496431Z
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734502131Z java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.util.IntRef, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'**
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734506931Z  at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(Native Method) ~[client-jar-sdk-1.14.0.jar!/:na]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734511832Z  at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(SpeechConfig.java:103) ~[client-jar-sdk-1.14.0.jar!/:na]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734516232Z  at com.namepronunciation.service.AzureTextToSpeechHelper.callAzureToTransformTextToSpeech(AzureTextToSpeechHelper.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734520732Z  at com.namepronunciation.service.NamePronunciationService.pronunce(NamePronunciationService.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734524832Z  at com.namepronunciation.controller.NamePronunciationController.pronunce(NamePronunciationController.java:81) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734529232Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2022-05-14T18:17:32.734533332Z  at

Thanks!
Mansoor

Answer (score 0):

- Before creating your stream class, make sure you call SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(KEY, REGION) (or one of the other from*() functions) at least once.
- The reason for this is that the speech sdk only loads the native dll at the "entry" classes automatically, such as SpeechConfig or Recognizer classes.
- Refer these links for more information:
  [Text Speech when SpeechConfig init got error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/660957/text-speech-when-speechconfig-init-got-error.html)
  [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/112)
  [Azure speech service can not use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/604021/azure-speech-service-can-not-use.html)